# Python/Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

Oi,

É possivel instalar um servidor localhost com Python/PostgreSQL?
Sei que é possivel com PHP/MySQL, como XAMPP, WAMPP, etc..

Preciso rodar um sistema que usa Python/PostgreSQL e meu servidor é Hostgator compartilhado e não oferece PostgreSQL.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Ná sua máquina? Sim.
No Hostgator? Provavelmente não, você pode conversar com o suporte deles para ver se eles não tem algum plano que atenda seus requisitos.

Para instalar nas sua máquina basta baixar o instalador do Postgre no site oficial:

https://www.postgresql.org/download/

E o python no:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Existe alguma ordem de instalação? Existe conflito com servidor XAMPP?

Comment: A ordem não faz diferença, e só não dá pra rodar em uma porta ja em uso.

Answer (score 1):

Se preferir, pode usar o docker também... tanto para o banco de dados quanto para o python. Geralmente e mais cômodo usar o docker para esse tipo de problema pois pode te poupar muito tempo com outros eventuais problemas.

Caso opte por utilizar o docker no Windows e preciso verificar se a sua versão do sistema operacional suporta o Hyper-V.

Comment: Luis, a pergunta é de 2017 e acho difícil que a Hostgator forneça docker para seus clientes. Se olhar na [lista de serviço](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/compatible-technologies) deles vai ver que sua resposta não faz sentido para a pergunta dele.